# Pivot/Crosstab/Unstack a Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

There is a necessity to break out the following data into a pivot table without any need for aggregation.  Given the normalization, I am trying to create a table that pivots the data so I can analyze times per incident_number.

Here is the Dataframe:

```
|incident|status|time|unit_num|
|123|dispatch|1/19/2019 09:04:59|ambulance1|
|123|enroute|1/19/2019 09:06:59|ambulance1|
|123|onscene|1/19/2019 09:14:59|ambulance1|
|123|available|1/19/2019 09:24:59|ambulance1|
|123|dispatch|1/19/2019 09:04:59|ambulance2|
|123|enroute|1/19/2019 09:08:59|ambulance2|
|123|onscene|1/19/2019 09:13:59|ambulance2|
|123|available|1/19/2019 09:34:59|ambulance2|
```

---

what I am trying to accomplish by either pivot/unstack is the following layout that is not producing the desired results

```
Incident | Unit | Dispatch | Enroute | Onscene | Available
123 | ambulance1 | associated times
123 | ambulance2 | associated times
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```
df = (
    df.pivot_table(
        index=['incident', 'unit_num'],
        columns='status',
        values='time',
        aggfunc=''.join)
    # .add_suffix('_time')
    .rename_axis(columns=None)
    .reset_index()
)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   incident    unit_num           available            dispatch  \
0       123  ambulance1  1/19/2019 09:24:59  1/19/2019 09:04:59   
1       123  ambulance2  1/19/2019 09:34:59  1/19/2019 09:04:59   

              enroute             onscene  
0  1/19/2019 09:06:59  1/19/2019 09:14:59  
1  1/19/2019 09:08:59  1/19/2019 09:13:59
```

Comment: I think this is the correct syntax.  The issue is that there are thousands of rows that should have been displayed yet only 7 rows with an incident_number of 0 were displayed.